# Cant see any containers, nor images, while many are running in VS Code - docker extension

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, asp.net-docker-extensions

I have logged into my docker hub account, run docker compose up, which had downloded all necessary images, run them and now everything is up and running. Yet, I do not see any of those mentioned in the title.

Likewise:
No networks, neither volumes visible - yet I have several up and running..
Looks like it can't connect to the active docker daemon ??

I also can not pull image from a docker hub (choosing from the extension menu): "Process exited with code 1"

However:
I do see everything correctly in the registries pane...

> Extension version: 1.23.3
> VS Code version: Code 1.74.3 (97dec172d3256f8ca4bfb2143f3f76b503ca0534, 2023-01-09T16:57:40.428Z)
> OS version: Linux x64 5.4.0-137-generic snap
> Sandboxed: No

Comment: Looks like my VSCode extension can't detect the docker daemon running on my PC => hence can't see anything happening locally in my docker environment ?

Comment: Hi, same problem here, have you find a solution?

Comment: @HedwinBonnavaud
Its a bug with a 'solution'
Check here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3783
and here: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3821